# On what basis does R programming language perform coercion when different type of data type are present in a vector

Tags: r

```
x <- c(1, "a")
```

This is code for creating a vector in R , and if you print the value you get

> "1" "a"

I need to know why the data type of 1 was changed to string? Any reason . Thanks in advance. Basically i need to know how does R performs coercion

Comment: please check `?c`

Comment: For the most common types of atomic vectors the hierarchy is logical < integer < double < character

Comment: `help('c')`, section Details, explains the coercion order.

Answer (score 0):

As per `?c`:

All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value, and all attributes except names are removed.

The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy:

`NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression`.

Therefore:

```
c(1, "a")   
#[1] "1" "a"
c(1, NULL)
#[1] 1
c(F, "a")
#[1] "FALSE" "a"
```